# (Javasript) Identify CR Line Break

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having some trouble to identify a CR line break inside a txt file.
It's a file that have a lot of CRLF line breaks and some CR line breaks (I can see that throght Notepad ++), and I want to identify where these CR line breaks are.

I will post the code that i'm trying to do:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/files/filetest.txt`);

const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: readStream
                    .on('error', function (error) {
                        console.log('Error to read file!'.red);
                        console.log(error);
                    }),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });


rl.on('line', (line) => {
        console.log(line.search(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g));
    });
```

But all i got from the console.log is -1, it can't find any linebreaks.

I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: why you need line break if you get whole single line ? (probably without last sign - line break sign)

Comment: Hi @Robert, because this file that i have from my company don't allow to have a CR line break to the proccess that we do, if it have, give us a lot o problems. I was doing this little code to identify where the CR line break is. That's why i need to know if in the end of the line it's a CRLF or CR.

Comment: Ok. But if you get more that one single line that means that your file have CR or CRLF yep? you can just count lines to find how many break lines you have. And if this line in event don't contain this last (break) char you can concatenate all lines to have file without breaks.

Comment: Are you sure there's a line-breaks in `line`? I am assuming the line-breaks were added when it concatenated all lines. So you're supposed to be `search`ing after all lines completed.

Comment: I think you are right @choz, I think there's no line-breaks with line. I will have to check the whole file.